# webkit hide content overflowing from border-radius

Tags: google-chrome, css, safari, webkit

http://jsfiddle.net/Bery8/3/

I have a node that has `position: relative`, and a  `border-radius`.  I'm trying to hide the content that flows out of the `border-radius`, wondering if anyone has a fix for this in webkit.  I need the `relative` positioning for another purpose and can't remove it.

Seems to work fine in mozilla.

```
<div>
    foo
    <span>content</span>
    <span>content</span>
    <span>content</span>
    <span>content</span>
    <span>content</span>
</div>

<style>
div {
    border        : 1px solid #000;
    border-radius : 20px;
    overflow      : auto;
    position      : relative;
    margin        : 10px;
    max-height    : 100px;
}

span {
    display    : block;
    background : teal;
    padding    : 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: hi check to this fiddle i think you may used last-child in span as like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Bery8/5/

Comment: @azad -- you got rid of my scrollbars.  They were there to show what was happening :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but if you add `border-radius: 20px` to the `span` element does it solve it?

Comment: sorry, wasn't 100% specific -- there's more content.  Updated fiddle/example.  The actual HTML is much larger / more complicated / scrolls

Answer (score 1):

add `border-radius` to `span` too

Comment: sorry, wasn't 100% specific -- there's more content.  Updated fiddle/example.  The actual HTML is much larger / more complicated / scrolls